# what does "Not Hannah Samuel more" mean?

Tags: meaning-in-context

I'm reading *A Woman of No Importance* by Oscar Wilde. Below is from Mrs. Arbuthnot to her son, Gerald:

> [...] Gerald, when you were naked I clothed you, when you were hungry I gave you food. Night and day all that long winter I tended you. No office is too mean, no care too lowly for the thing we women love- and oh! how I loved you. Not Hannah Samuel more. And you needed love, for you were weakly, and only love could have kept you alive. Only love can keep any one alive. [...]

Really, I couldn't understand "Not Hannah Samuel more", from a grammar point of view. What does it mean actually?

Are some parts omitted? What is the complete form of this sentence?

#### Background

I suppose Hannah and Samuel are from Bible, below is quoted from [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hannah_%28Bible%29):

> In the biblical narrative, Hannah is one of two wives of Elkanah; the other, Peninnah, who bore children to Elkanah, but Hannah remained childless.
>
> Nevertheless, Elkanah preferred Hannah. Every year Elkanah would offer a sacrifice at the Shiloh sanctuary, and give Penninah and her children a portion but he gave Hannah a double portion "because he loved her, and the LORD had closed her womb" (NIV). One day Hannah went up to the temple, and prayed with great weeping (I Samuel 1:10), while Eli the High Priest was sitting on a chair near the doorpost. In her prayer she asked God for a son and in return she vowed to give the son back to God for the service of the Shiloh priests. She promised he would remain a Nazarite all the days of his life.
>
> Eli thought she was drunk and questioned her. When she explained herself, he sent her away and effectively said that her prayer would be heard and her desire granted. As promised, she conceived and bore a son. She called his name Samuel, "since she had asked the Lord for him" (1 Samuel 1:20 NAB). She raised him until he was weaned and brought him to the temple along with a sacrifice. The first 10 verses of 1 Samuel 2 record her song of praise to the Lord for answering her petition. Eli announced another blessing on Hannah, and she conceived 3 more sons and 2 daughters, making six in total.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

In isolation, *Not Hannah Samuel more* is an ungrammatical utterance. In the context of the paragraph, though, we can make out that this is a highly elliptical way of saying:

> Hannah did not love Samuel more.

This sort of ellipsis is very rarely found in modern speech or writing.

Comment: I'm not convinced. Most citation have a comma between "Hannah" and "Samuel", which doesn't fit this reading.

Comment: @FumbleFingers I can assure you that in Victorian/Edwardian literary English this use of the comma is not unusual. "John loved Mary, and Mary, John" is something I just made up, but is typical; if you need an exemplar I'll try to find you one, but it'll take me a while.

Comment: @StoneyB: I'm perfectly well aware of the comma usage in *your* example - it's a little stiff and formal today, but unexceptional. My point is that if we accept JSBձոգչ's interpretation here, the comma is ***definitely not valid***. If the comma is supposed to be there, the only feasible interpretation is the one I've given. To that extent, both interpretations are valid - the "correct" choice being entirely dependent on whether one accepts the comma or not.

Comment: @FumbleFingers On the contrary: Victorian usage is not so circumscribed. It does not require the elliptical comma, but it permits it. "How I loved you. Not Hannah [loved] Samuel more!" not only makes allusive sense, it is reinforced by what follows. It is the same usage (with a full stop rather than a semi-colon) as that prescribed in the NASA handbook cited [here](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/30553/how-do-you-punctuate-elliptical-constructions).

Comment: +1; this is the only way to read that sentence (in context) that makes any sense.

Comment: @StoneyB: This disagreement is going nowhere. The comma, if present, implies a pause in speech - not the omission of a word. I can't think of any way to vocalise that four-word sentence *with a pause*, and still convey JSBձոգչ's meaning. I'm reasonably familiar with standard Victorian intonation, and in this case I don't think it differs from modern style - to get this particular meaning you actually *have* to run "Hannah" and "Samuel" together without a pause.

Comment: @FumbleFingers It *may* imply a pause, or it *may* imply an ellipsis. In any case, the earliest editions do omit the comma - that privately printed in Paris in [1903](http://archive.org/stream/awomannoimporta00wildgoog#page/n152/mode/2up) and the commercial edition in [1904](http://archive.org/stream/womanofnoimporta00wildrich#page/134/mode/2up). We may suppose that these were based on the version which premiered on 19 April 1893, and the comma crept into later editions to make the syntax clearer.

Comment: The sentence is correct as is. Sentence fragments are a normal part of the language. Grammar school not withstanding. Out of context it would be hard to parse, of course.

Comment: @StoneyB: All I can say is I've never heard of a comma being used instead of three dots to indicate elided words. Also, I assume when JSBձոգչ says the phrasing is "elliptical", he means "roundabout, convoluted", rather than that the word *"loved"* is elided between the two names. He's addressed OP's version, *without the comma*, which is fine by me.

Comment: @FumbleFingers There's a lot of confusion around these terms. [*Ellipsis*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ellipsis_(linguistics)) meant originally the figure of speech which omits one or more words to be supplied by the hearer - something which was never there - and it retains that meaning in grammar, rhetoric and linguistics. *(Dots of) ellipsis* is the somewhat ill-chosen name for the punctuation mark which, *inter alia*, signals that one or more words which *were* in a quoted original have been omitted - an *elision*. And *elision* also denotes sounds omitted in speech.

Comment: @FumbleFingers And just to confuse things even more: *OED 1* - the relevant fascicle was published in 1891 - acknowledges a mark of punctuation called *ellipsis* - but it's the dash!, used to mark the omission of letters in a printed word. The name "ellipsis" for the dots is relatively recent.